# Fossil-SCM Pulling only a specific file

Tags: version-control, pull, fossil

I was trying to pull only a specific file from the fossil scm but the only reply I got was

```
 Fossil internal error: repository does not exist or is in an unreadable directory: blahblah
```

the commands I tried to use was

```
 fossil pull "file" -R "http://user@ip/folder/to/fossil"
 fossil pull "" -R "http://user@ip/folder/to/fossil/file"
```

I don't understand the documentation. If I wanted to just download a specific file without opening and cloning the repo, how would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't **pull** a single file from a fossil server.  Pulling retrieves ALL the (new) changes in the remote repository into your local repository.  It's the read part of the `sync` command, and it requires you to have cloned the repository first. (The `-R` command-line option always indicates a *local* repository).

But it seems to me that what you want, is simply to **download** a specific file from the remote repository. To do that, just use your browser to navigate the fossil server's web site (I'm using Fossil's own source code repository as an example):

http://fossil-scm.org/fossil/dir?ci=trunk

http://fossil-scm.org/fossil/tree?ci=trunk

and click on the file you want. On the page displaying the file, there's a `Download` button which will let you download that version of that specific file.

If the file is not text or HTML, you can just download the file using http, using a so-called *documentation* URL:

```
http://<server>/doc/<version>/<path-to-file>
```

For example, let's say you want to download the `trunk` version of the file `www/concept1.gif` from the main Fossil repository. That can be achieved by downloading the following URL:

http://fossil-scm.org/fossil/doc/trunk/www/concept1.gif

That URL is composed as follows:

- `http://fossil-scm.org/fossil` is the repository's location;
- `/doc/` indicates that you want to access the repository's files directly;
- `trunk` indicates the check-in you want to access. This can also be a check-in identifier (like [e319e8e870](http://fossil-scm.org/fossil/info/e319e8e870)) or a tag (like [pending-review](http://fossil-scm.org/fossil/timeline?t=pending-review)). If you specify a tag or branch name, you'll get the file associated with the last check-in with that tag, respectively in that branch;
- `/www/concept1.gif` is the path within the repository to the file you want to access.

**Note** that if the file you requested is a wiki, text, or HTML page, fossil will add its header and footer to it.

Comment: I guess that's what I'll have to use, I tried navigating to the web version of the file. (They were jpg) and simply dragging them off but the names didn't follow instead it had it's hash name. But at the time I tried I couldn't figure out how to get to the direct link like you show above. I'm going to give it a try in a few minutes.